# ACF Sorting by certain field Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to display my posts in alphabetical order by a ACF. I have the below but it doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks in advance!

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'sale',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'sales_status',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',

));

if( $the_query->have_posts() ):

while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
```

Comment: Hi Brian, looking at [the codex documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), the last three lines of your code seem to look like they should work. Do you have an opportunity to try doing a query on a different `post_type` like [`post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-type-parameters) or maybe trying a different `meta_key`? Maybe that could help narrow down the issue if the problem has to do with something related to the `array` values of the `WP_Query()`, unless I'm missing something in the last three lines.

Comment: Thanks summea, I have tried a different ACF for that post type, still the same order.

Comment: Oh, so the ordering is the part that isn't working?

Comment: Correct, I have the info coming in but I can't get them to order by the ACF of sales_status. I have Available or Closed, I want all the Available ones first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve your issue, but after hearing that your issue has to do with the ordering of your query and then looking at the [`WP_Query` codex documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters) a little more, it looks like your query might need to have an `order` parameter added.

In the above documentation, it indicates that the default sort order of the `orderby` parameter is `DESC` (descending). This sounds accurate because with the `Available` and `Closed` `sales_status` options [that you noted in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247239/acf-sorting-by-certain-field-issue?noredirect=1#comment117123744_66247239), you want the `Available` ones listed first but that's not currently happening with the order (because with descending order, `Closed` comes before `Available`). If the default behavior were `ASC` (ascending), I think your results would be in the order you were expecting.

For your query, it might be worth trying to add a specific `order` parameter to set the sorting direction. Thus, your adjusted query could look like this:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'sale',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'sales_status',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
));
```

Does that help with your situation?

---

**Update:**

Upon further reading in [the codex documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters), it looks like the `order` parameter might not need to be added after all for your particular type of use case. In the context of using `meta_value` for the `orderby` parameter, [the documentation states](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters): `Note also that the sorting will be alphabetical which is fine for strings (i.e. words) ...`. Sorry for suggesting the `order` parameter when it seems like that might not be necessary when using the `meta_value`.

Comment: Still no movement I have no idea what's going. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Brian, if your data is not too sensitive, would it be possible for you to try temporarily putting in this line of code somewhere in your program (`<?php echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request; ?>`) from [this other post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/4818/66361). I'm wondering if that would give you some output as far as the actual query that is being run by WordPress. If the query output doesn't have sensitive data, maybe that query output could be added to your original question post? It might give a clue as to why the ordering is happening the way it is happening.

Comment: It's definitely not picking up my query, this is what I get: SELECT wp_cqswki_posts.* FROM wp_cqswki_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (wp_cqswki_posts.ID = '3133') AND wp_cqswki_posts.post_type = 'page' ORDER BY wp_cqswki_posts.menu_order, wp_cqswki_posts.post_date DESC

Comment: Okay, thanks for trying that. I wonder if [this other approach](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/38829/66361) would show you the query related to your question. Underneath your `$the_query = new WP_Query(array(...));` code, would it be possible to temporarily put this: `echo $the_query->request;`?

Comment: This is what that returns SELECT wp_cqswki_posts.* FROM wp_cqswki_posts INNER JOIN wp_cqswki_postmeta ON ( wp_cqswki_posts.ID = wp_cqswki_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_cqswki_postmeta.meta_key = 'sales_status' ) AND wp_cqswki_posts.post_type = 'sale' AND (wp_cqswki_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_cqswki_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled') GROUP BY wp_cqswki_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_cqswki_posts.menu_order, wp_cqswki_postmeta.meta_value DESC

Comment: Hmm, I might have to come back to this finding later, but at first glance from your program's output, it seems strange that `wp_cqswki_posts.menu_order` is part of the `ORDER BY` statement (especially being in front of the `meta_value` part) and that there is a `DESC` at the end. I still think if it was `ASC` at the end of the generated query, it might be in the order you are looking for, here.

Comment: If I do a meta-value of Available, it only pulls the Available posts. So it's working somewhat.

Comment: I had a plugin install called 'Post Order Type' it was hijacking the query. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No problem about that! I'm glad you found what was causing the issue! I remember hearing in the past somewhere that plugins can sometimes cause issues; sorry that I didn't think of that earlier, though.

Comment: It was your idea to echo out the query which made me realize the issue. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad it was helpful! But I think the "echoing out the query" idea itself for your situation mostly came from the people on [these](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/4818/66361) [posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/38829/66361) and any help from Jesus! When it comes to debugging SQL queries in general, though, I do like to try to see what is really being produced in the background. Thanks for being willing to try the debugging steps along the way!